# Why removing npm means removing nodejs as well on CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, node.js, npm

I'm trying to remove `npm` (EPEL repository), but `yum` wants me to remove `nodejs` as well. It's `nodejs` that is `npm`'s dependency. Not the other way around. `nodejs` can live without `npm` just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm no Yum user, but maybe NodeJS was installed as a dependency for npm and that's why it wants to remove NodeJS as well? You could try going along with it and then installing NodeJS again.

Comment: You may be right, but the question is not about how to deal with it. But rather about what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. I had both EPEL and NodeSource repositories added. It appears `repoquery -R` and `yum deplist` report information regarding only the latest version. In my case it was from NodeSource repository. The following command:

```
yum deplist --showduplicates nodejs
```

showed that `nodejs` from EPEL does depend on `npm`. Alternativaly, you can run:

```
repoquery -R --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=epel nodejs
```

or (not at all convenient, no separation between packages):

```
repoquery -R --show-duplicates nodejs
```